# How to get next highest number from mysql rows, given one row id

Tags: mysql, sql

How to get next highest number from mysql rows, given one row id.

Eg.

```
    Categories | sort_order

    Animal | 400
    Cars   | 500
>
    Vans   | 550
```

Now I want to add a category under Cars, over Vans which I have to check what is next highest number after 500.

So when I add 400 should return 500, when 500 should retrun 550.

Comment: Do you ask for 501 or 550?

Comment: 550 has to be, so everything from 501 - 549 is free to add in beetween.

Comment: I would add that if you intend `Vans` to be a subcategory of `Cars` then depending on the sort order of the two categories is not good database design. You might do better with a self-referencing table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be as simple as the following:

```
SELECT MIN(sort_order) FROM mytable
 WHERE sort_order > 500;
```

Comment: @Flakerim in SQL, if any data in a set function is null, the entire result is null. So you have some rows that have a sort_order=null, so you'll need to either cleanup your data to have no nulls in that field, or filter those rows out in the WHERE clause with `... and sort_order IS NOT NULL)

Comment: In fact there wasn't any record with sort order 500

Answer (score 0):

```
select min(sort_order) + 1 from tablename where sort_order >= 500
```

Untested, but should work.

Comment: @Flakerim in SQL, if any data in a set function is null, the entire result is null. So you have some rows that have a sort_order=null, so you'll need to either cleanup your data to have no nulls in that field, or filter those rows out in the WHERE clause with `... and sort_order IS NOT NULL)

Comment: BTW, this with give you 501